# MASH-2 hash function

Tags: math, hash-function, number-theory

We have taken the MASH-2 hash function in a college course, and in the exam we are confronted
with questions to calculate something like this ((62500)^257)) mod (238194151) using only a scientific calculator. now i know some theories with a^b (mod n) but the problem i present above is even hard to calculate manually. i think it would take about 15 minutes to solve this. i would like to know if there is a faster way to do this. or even if there is some way to do it in binary (convert the number to binary and then do some manipulations). i need to able to do this by hand with a scientific calculator.

Comment: As written this is scarcely a question at all, there's no question mark and no sentence whose construction directly points to it needing a question mark.  Leaving that aside, and leaving aside my doubts that this question is on-topic here at SO (it smells strongly of maths): solicitations for assistance with studies get much better answers if the student shows some evidence of having already applied what she has been taught and got stuck.  What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Believe me i have tried everything. and my question is obvious: is there a way to calculate a^b(mod n) in a faster way than Euler's theory.

Comment: I don't remember off the top of my head, but I believe there are some theorems in number theory that greatly simplify the problem when a and m are relatively prime.  If this is still open when I get home from work tonight I'll try to find my number theory books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this special case the prime factor decomposition of `a = 62500 = 2² ⋅ 5⁶` is very simple.
You can use this to calculate `(2²)²⁵⁷` and `(5⁶)²⁵⁷` first and calculate then the product.
But the problem I see, is that for `n = 238194151` my scientific calculator can not calculate `n²` correctly. If your calculator can do this, it should be no problem.

Since `gcd(a, b) = 1` you also could use [CRT](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinesischer_Restsatz), but I'm not sure if you can find the prime factors `n = 13  ⋅ 59 ⋅ 310553` with only a scientific calculator. If so, this will make it much easier. You just calculate `a²⁵⁷ mod (13⋅59)` and `a²⁵⁷ mod 310553` and put the results together with CRT.

You can also use only [Exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) so you only have to calculate 8 squares.

Comment: I can't even remember I asked this question. Anyway, your explanation sounds reasonable so I am going to award you the correct answer. Thank you.